# How do I throw and exception using `if` and `else` if the user enter something that isn't a valid integer?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program that adds numbers. The program takes input from the user as an integer value and gives him a total of both numbers. But I want that when the user enters any character besides the number, a custom error is written to the console. How do you do that with `if` and `else`?

My code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double firstnum, secondnum, total;

        Console.WriteLine("FIRST NUMBER");
        firstnum = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (Console.ReadLine == char)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error... error wrong keyword, enter only numbers...");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("SECOND NUMBER");
        secondnum = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        total = firstnum + secondnum;
        Console.WriteLine("TOTAL VALUE IS =" + total);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `if (Console.ReadLine == char);` at least 3 errors in that single line of code :(

Answer (score 1):

First read the string into a string variable. Then use `TryParse` to turn it into a number. It'll return `false` if the string is no valid number, which you can use to display your error.

```
var firstNumAsString = Console.ReadLine();
int firstNum;
if (!int.TryParse(firstNumAsString, out firstNum))
{
    Console.WriteLine("error... error wrong keyword, enter only numbers...");
    return;
}
```

If you want to throw an exception instead of just displaying an error, use `int.Parse`. It'll throw a `FormatException` or an `OverflowException` if the input isn't valid.

Comment: Isn't it `Int32.TryParse();` which takes two arguments?

Comment: I spent the whole day copy&pasting c code into C#, and fixing the compiler errors. That numbs the brain :P